# Shortcut to a manipulation of the current URL

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, browser, shortcuts

I'm using Firefox (9.0.1 in Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit) and I'm wondering how to make a shortcut to a certain manipulation of the current URL.

Here's an example to clarify. I'm browsing http://askubuntu.com and I want to go to an URL that is a manipulation of the current URL, namely the URL that is "http://askubuntu.com" with "meta" inserted after "http://", by pressing a certain key combination, e.g. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>. How can I do this?

I guess this requires two particular things:

- A device to manipulate the current URL, i.e. a device to insert a certain string into a certain position of the current URL.
- A device to bind the above procedure to a key combination.

I don't know how to make this happen. Maybe making a bookmark with javascript or use of greasemonkey can achieve it?

Comment: First of all, what OS do you use?

Comment: @MichaelK I've updated my question to include what OS I use.

Comment: As far as I know, there is a standard software for keyboard shortcuts in the ubuntu system settings. I don't know if it does what you want to do, but you may want to check it.

Comment: @MichaelK Do you mean gnome-keybinding-properties? There's is no keybinding to what I'm after there. I'm *not* after something equivalent to Ctrl+L.

Comment: Are you looking for a browser addon, or do you want to bind global macros to your keys?

Comment: @MichaelK I want the keybindings to be local to Firefox. I don't mind an addon as long as it's reasonably light and stable.

Comment: I know there is a macro addon for firefox called iMacros, but I'm not sure if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: @MichaelK iMacros does not seem to do it since macros are based on a certain URL. What I want should work for any URL (to insert a certain string a certain point in an URL).

Answer (score 1):

One extension that looks like it should work would be keyconfig.  It appears like you can easily assign what would be a javascript bookmarklet to a key combination.  So all you would have to do is do is come up with a [bookmarklet that adjusted the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689553/bookmarklet-to-edit-current-url).

- http://kb.mozillazine.org/Keyconfig_extension
- http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=72994
- http://kb.mozillazine.org/Keyconfig_extension:_Firefox

Comment: I will look into this. I'm not sure which is best to manipulate with javascript, `window.location` or `location` as indicated by the answers of that URL. If I'm successful I might write a full description of what I did as an answer (unless you elaborate your answer into one).

Comment: According to https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/functions-for-keyconfig/ it's not available for Firefox 6.0.2. So this won't do.

Comment: The 'functions-for-keyconfig' addon is not the keyconfig addon I mentioned.  It is something else.  The correct link for keyconfig can be found on this page.  http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=72994.  I just installed it on 6.0.2 to verify.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I've installed it now but I'm stuck in trying to figure out how to access a bookmarklet from keyconfig. How do I do that?